# How to reduce network round trip between hbase hadoop and application server

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, boot, sprint

we have an spring boot application which is connecting to hbase using phoneix framework.
This app is deployed in private cloud and hbase db is in different geographical location.
There was a network latency issue identified between hadoop and app server.
while we check with network team we got to know that, we have many round trip between hadoop and app server and each time hadoop was sending only 6400 bytes.

Network team suggested to check with hadoop to send more than 6400 byes at a time so that, network round trip can be avoided.

what is the hadoop property / phoneix client side app property we need to configure so that, hadoop wil send more than 6400 bytes each  time ?